# How to get associations in Doctrine entity?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I hope it's possible in Doctrine2. I know Propel does that automatically. What I want to do is this:

I have two tables:

```
workflow (id, name)
inbox (id, workflow_id, name)
```

And two entities:

```
Workflow and Inbox
```

In my Inbox entity I, of course, have this (to relate two tables):

```
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Workflow")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
   */
  protected $workflow;
```

Everything works great. However, I want to be able to get inboxes from the Workflow entity that are associated with that workflow. I can't find how to do it.

Propel does that very simple, you would just do something like this:

```
$workflow = WorkflowQuery::create()
  ->filterById(1)
  ->findOne(1);

$inboxes = $workflow->getInboxs() 
//Propel just addes 's' to methods that return associations
```

How, similar this can be done in Doctrine2? Something like this:

```
$workflow = $this->getRepository('MyBundle:Workflow')->findById(1);
$inboxes = $workflow->getInboxes();
```

So, is there a way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Change in controller:

```
$workflow = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Workflow')->find(1);
$inboxes = $workflow->getInboxes();
```

Don't forget that you need

```
// Workflow entity
public function __construct()
{
    // make `use` statement for this, not long
    $this->inboxes = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection() ;
}
```

and

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Inbox", mappedBy="workflow", cascade={"persist"})
*/
protected $inboxes ;
public function getInboxes() { return $this->inboxes ; }
// setInboxes(), addInbox(), removeInbox() here
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got it to work. But what do you mean by "make `use` statement for this, ..."? I remember getting error message that said something about `use`. Maybe you can clarify this for me. Thanks again.

Comment: After `namespace`, put `use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection ;` and in __construct() method, do this: `$this->inboxes = new ArrayCollection() ;`.